# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no "somefile" in java.library.path

Tags: java, dll, jvm

I am trying to load a system library "somesimplejava". I am passing its directory path as an argument to the JVM in eclipse JRE environment VM arguments.

```
-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\{username}\Desktop
```

This path contains `somesimplejava.dll` and `somesimplejava.jar`. Still, I am facing the below error while running its test case.

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no somesimplejava in java.library.path

Comment: The first step would be to insert a `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`, to check whether your option made it into the actual system properties.

Answer (score 0):

In order to define the java.library.path property in Eclipse, the following steps must be completed:

- Select your project in the Package Explorer area and press a right click on it.
- Select Build Path → Configure Build Path... option.
- In the appearing window, select the Libraries tab.
- Then, expand the JRE System library option and select the Native library location.
- Click on the Edit... button at the right panel.
- Locate the required library and then click OK.
- Close the window.

Comment: I don't get the point why the run time argument to JVM is not considered

Comment: Must not forget the quotation marks, otherwise there are problems with spaces in PATH. -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\{username}\Desktop"

Comment: uses this:-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\${user.name}\Desktop"